# a2e datetimepicker - Datetimepicker doesn't show on both input focus and click on icon

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using a2e datetimepicker. I want to open datetimepicker on both input focus and icon clicked. But both not working together.

Here is my code.

**1) In this datepicker will open on icon clicked but not on input focus.**

```
          <label class="col-lg-4 control-label my-label">Date of Birth</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error' : (BirthDate.invalid && IsBtnClicked)}">
              <input class="form-control" tabindex="1" a2e-datetimepicker [(ngModel)]="EmpPersonalDetails.DateOfBirth" [options]="options"
                #BirthDate="ngModel" name="BirthDate" required />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar nopad2 fa-lg"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
                </div>
```

**2) In this datepicker will open on input focus but not when icon clicked.**

```
<label class="control-label my-label">From Date</label>
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" (focus)="onFocus(fromDatePicker)" a2e-datetimepicker [(ngModel)]="fromDate" [options]="options"
              name="fromDate" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" (click)="onFocus(fromDatePicker)">
              <span class="fa fa-calendar nopad2 fa-lg" #fromDatePicker></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And on focus event in ts :

```
onFocus(element) {
    element.click();
}
```

I tried to merge both of them but still its not working.